# MySQL index slowing down query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing

```
MySQL Server version: 5.0.95
Tables All: InnoDB
```

I am having an issue with a MySQL db query. Basically I am finding that if I index a particular varchar(50) field **tag.name**, my queries take longer (x10) than not indexing the field. I am trying to speed this query up, however my efforts seem to be counter productive.

The culprit line and field seems to be:

```
WHERE `t`.`name` IN ('news','home')
```

I have noticed that if i query the `tag` table directly without a join using the same criteria and with the name field indexed, i do not have the issue.. It actually works faster as expected.

EXAMPLE Query **

```
      SELECT `a`.*, `u`.`pen_name`
        FROM `tag_link` `tl`
  INNER JOIN `tag` `t`
          ON `t`.`tag_id` = `tl`.`tag_id`
  INNER JOIN `article` `a` 
          ON `a`.`article_id` = `tl`.`link_id`
  INNER JOIN `user` `u`
          ON `a`.`user_id` = `u`.`user_id`   
       WHERE `t`.`name` IN ('news','home')
         AND `tl`.`type` = 'article'
         AND `a`.`featured` = 'featured'
    GROUP BY `article_id`
       LIMIT 0 , 5
```

EXPLAIN with index **

```
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys            | key     | key_len | ref               | rows | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | range  | PRIMARY,name             | name    | 152     | NULL              |    4 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tl    | ref    | tag_id,link_id,link_id_2 | tag_id  | 4       | portal.t.tag_id   |   10 | Using where                                               | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,fk_article_user1 | PRIMARY | 4       | portal.tl.link_id |    1 | Using where                                               | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                  | PRIMARY | 4       | portal.a.user_id  |    1 |                                                           | 
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------+---------+---------+-------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

EXPLAIN without index **

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys            | key     | key_len | ref                 | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | index  | PRIMARY,fk_article_user1 | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL                | 8742 | Using where | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                  | PRIMARY | 4       | portal.a.user_id    |    1 |             | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tl    | ref    | tag_id,link_id,link_id_2 | link_id | 4       | portal.a.article_id |    3 | Using where | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                  | PRIMARY | 4       | portal.tl.tag_id    |    1 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+-------+--------+--------------------------+---------+---------+---------------------+------+-------------+
```

**TABLE CREATE**

```
CREATE TABLE `tag` (
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('layout','image') NOT NULL,
  `create_dttm` datetime default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`tag_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=43077 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**INDEXS**

```
SHOW INDEX FROM tag_link;
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| tag_link |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | tag_link_id | A         |       42023 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tag_link |          1 | tag_id   |            1 | tag_id      | A         |       10505 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| tag_link |          1 | link_id  |            1 | link_id     | A         |       14007 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+

SHOW INDEX FROM article;
+---------+------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name         | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+---------+------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| article |          0 | PRIMARY          |            1 | article_id  | A         |        5723 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| article |          1 | fk_article_user1 |            1 | user_id     | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| article |          1 | create_dttm      |            1 | create_dttm | A         |        5723 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+---------+------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

**Final Solution**
It seems that MySQL is just sorted the data incorrectly. In the end it turned out faster to look at the tag table as a sub query returning the ids.

Comment: What are the indexes on the other tables? What cardinality is reported for each of the indexes? Have you analyzed them recently?

Comment: agree with sym, try yo analize it looks like the filesort is messing up

Comment: please take a look to this page: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/

Comment: What indexes do you have in the `tag_link` and in the `article` table?

Comment: Also, can you test performance if you add `ORDER BY NULL` ?

Comment: Added the index to the main post.. Also order by null actually removes the filesort, how come ??.. In addition using order by null is a few times slower and added a "Using Join Buffer" to the EXPLAIN.

Comment: How many actual different tag.names do you have in your table?

Comment: how come there's only 10505 tag_id? are you sure `select count(distinct tag.name) from tag` gives 21000?

Comment: tag names can be dupes.. its the tag.name + tag.type that make the unique key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How big are your tables?
I noticed in the first explain you have a "Using temporary; Using filesort" which is bad. Your query is likely being dumped to disc which makes it way slower than in memory queries.
Also try to avoid using "select *" and instead query the minimum fields needed.

Comment: Its am example, but thanks for the tip. I know using file sort is an issue but i do not understand why its happening. When i add the index a filesort is used.. Drop the index and it works fine..

Comment: i just ran into this thread: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?115,73760,73760#msg-73760 their suggestion is to make a lookup table for your tag.name so you use integers in your data tables separate from the names itself

Comment: This was how i solved the issue.. It was faster to do an single lookup on the tag table by name as a sub query. :D.. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that article_id is the primary key for the article table.

Since you're grouping by article_id, MySQL needs to return the records in order by that column, in order to perform the GROUP BY.

You can see that without the index, it scans all records in the article table, but they're at least in order by article_id, so no later sort is required. The LIMIT optimization can be applied here, since it's already in order, it can just stop after it gets five rows.

In the query with the index on tag.name, instead of scanning the entire articles table, it utilizes the index, but against the tag table, and starts there. Unfortunately, when doing this, the records must later be sorted by article.article_id in order to complete the GROUP BY clause. The LIMIT optimization can't be applied since it must return the entire result set, then order it, in order to get the first 5 rows.

In this case, MySQL just guesses wrongly.

Without the LIMIT clause, I'm guessing that using the index is faster, which is maybe what MySQL was guessing.