# How can INDEX slow down a LIKE query?

Tags: mysql, indexing

This is a duplicate neither of [MySQL index slowing down query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931143/mysql-index-slowing-down-query) nor of [Slow search by index query LIKE% MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745681/slow-search-by-index-query-like-mysql)

On a very simple table, I tried a very simple query, with and without a specific index.

Table (40 000 lines):

```
id                      int(11)     
shipping_address_id     int(11)     
billing_address_id      int(11)     
label                   varchar(100)
code                    varchar(15) 
email                   varchar(100)
```

Query : `SELECT email FROM table WHERE email LIKE "%yahoo%"`

Without an INDEX on "email", it takes 0.0035s. With this INDEX, however, it takes 0.021s, which is 7x slower.

Yet the same INDEX does accelerate an equality query by 50x (`WHERE email = "me@yahoo.com"`).

So, why is the `LIKE` query negatively affected by the INDEX?

**EDIT TYPO:** The query originally stated `LIKE "yahoo"`while it should read `LIKE "%yahoo%"`, my apologize.

**EDIT FOR CLARITY:** the table is InnoDB, and i am comparing speeds of the same queries. In the first case (the "LIKE" case), the query is 7x slower with an INDEX on the compared field. In the second case ("=") the query is 50x faster with the INDEX.

Comment: You are comparing two different queries. You haven't isolated properly for just using an index or not. Your test is invalid.

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't understand your point. I'm doing comparison with only one query ("LIKE"). The other query ("=") is just here to show that the INDEX works with it. Didnt you read too fast before you say i write invalid things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index implicitly solves (and speeds up) queries with *comparison* operators: =, <, >. If you have an index on the `email` field, and a `LIKE` query, MySQL has *still* to retrieve **all** the elements in the index, and apply the regexp to them.

If the query was

```
 WHERE email LIKE 'yahoo%com'
```

you could speed it up by observing that `email` must be between 'yahoo' and 'yahoo[' (let's assume that [ comes after z in lexicographic order, and can not appear in the `email` field). Then changing the query to

```
WHERE (email BETWEEN 'yahoo' AND 'yahoo[') AND email LIKE 'yahoo%com'
```

would yield a benefit, because the index would quickly pre-select a smaller set of rows, and *then* the regexp would be run against those only (on a field that's already available, because it's in the index, so no table lookups are needed).

But in this case, in practice, *MySQL has to do a full table scan*; except that it is doing so on the *index*. The cost of doing this can be actually **higher** than that of a "true" table scan. In some cases MySQL would realize this, and you would see that the index is then actually *not used* by the query at all (depending on how recently it has been analyzed, its size, and other factors), and MySQL prefers to employ a full table scan.

The other case in which an index might help you, by gathering data needed for the query, does also not apply because you are only asking for the `email` field, which is the one computation is being done on. So again the index yields no performance increase whatsoever.

If you want an index that speeds up this kind of `WHERE`, you need a `FULLTEXT` index, not a "ordinary" index.

Comment: MySql claims that they can use an index where the LIKE does not begin with a wildcard. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html
So, I believe something else is going on here.

Comment: Possibly the table is not `InnoDB`, and has a non-BTree index. BTree index manager automatically implements the "restrict then regexp" optimization, other managers do not. Another possibility is that the indexed LIKE implements a slower string-matching algorithm than the non-indexed LIKE (actually, when I answered, I believe that the OP's query contained a wildcard after 'yahoo')

Comment: Thank you Iserni for your developed answer. I'm sorry because there was a typo, see the EDIT in the question. So your original answer (in which you thought there was wildcards) applies to my real question :) I understand that the LIKE is done on an index instead of the full column when the column is indexed, and that a LIKE on an index is not implemented the same way, which could lead in poorer performances. Still it's odd, but now i understand. Thank you.