# MySQL query is slower after index create

Tags: mysql, indexing

At first i will write some information about my test table.
This is books table with 665647 rows of data.
Below you can see how it looks.

[image]

I made 10 same queries for books with price equal

```
select * from books where price = 10
```

Execution time for all 10 queries was 9s 663ms.

After that i created index which you can see here:
[image]

i tried to run same 10 queries one more time.
Execution time for them was 21s 996ms.

```
show index from books;
```

Showed very wired data for me.
Possible value is just one!

[image]

What did i wrong? I was sure indexes are thing that can make our queries faster, not slower.

i found this topic : [MySQL index slowing down query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931143/mysql-index-slowing-down-query)
but to be honest i dont really understand this especially Cardinality column
in my table books i have two possible values for price field at this moment
10 and 30 still `show index from books;` shows 1
[image]

@Edit1
SHOW CREATE TABLE books

Result:

```
    CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `isbn` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `price` double(8,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `author_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `books_isbn_unique` (`isbn`),
  KEY `books_author_id_foreign` (`author_id`),
  KEY `books_price_index` (`price`),
  CONSTRAINT `books_author_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=665648 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

@Edit2
I added new index `create index nameIndex on books (name)`
[image]
Which have big Cardinality value.

When i tried to do this query `select * from books where name ='Inventore cumque quis.'`
Before and after index create i can see the difference in execution time.
But still i dont understand how index'es works. I was sure about one thing - if i create new index in my database is creating new data structure with data which fit to this index.
For example if i have orws with price 10, 30 i got two "Tables" where are rows with these prices.

Comment: provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE books` and `EXPLAIN EXTENDED select * from books where price = 10`. Also, this question is probably off-topic here, you would get better chance for answer on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JakiLim        This URL may help you understand some of indexing details.  https://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: Run ANALYZE TABLE books; to freshen up your table statistics.  Then run your select COUNT(*) from books where price = 10 for the count books prices at 10 something. Have you considered using something like SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books WHERE price BETWEEN 10.00 and 10.99; ?

Comment: Dup of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/294195/mysql-query-is-slower-after-index-create

Answer (score 5):

Is it realistic to have so many rows with the same `price`?  Is it realistic to return 444K rows from a query?  I ask these because query optimization is predicated on "normal" data.

An index (eg, `INDEX(price)`) is useful when looking for a `price` that occurs a small number of times.  In fact, the Optimizer shuns the index if it sees that the value being searched for occurs more than about 20% of the time.  Instead, it would simply ignore the index and do what you tested first--simply scan the entire table, ignoring any rows that don't match.

You should be able to see that by doing

```
EXPLAIN select * from books where price = 10
```

with and without the index.  Alternatively, you can try:

```
EXPLAIN select * from books IGNORE INDEX(books_price_index) where price = 10
EXPLAIN select * from books FORCE INDEX(books_price_index) where price = 10
```

But, ...  It seems that the Optimizer did not ignore the index.  I see that the "cardinality" of `price` is "1", which implies that there is only one distinct value in that column.  This 'statistic' is either incorrect or misleading.  Please run this and see what changes:

```
ANALYZE TABLE books;
```

This will recompute the stats via a few random probes, and *may* change that "1" to perhaps "2".

General advice: Beware of benchmarks that run against fabricated data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755569/why-does-the-cardinality-of-an-index-in-mysql-remain-unchanged-when-i-add-a-new

Cardinality didnt get updated after index was created. Try to run the analyze table command.

Comment: but i have 400k+ rows with price 10 and 200k rows with price 30 beofre i created an index